# Login Using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am very very new to HtmlUnit. I want to  know do I am able to login to a site using htmlunit and perform some operations in the site for example I want to login to my office portal and to aplly a leave.

I  am using html unit and it shows some errors, is its possible to do with html unit or **are there any other tools I can use for this purpose**... 
Here is my code

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);        
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

final HtmlPage page1 =  webClient.getPage("http://www.ccstechnologies.org/login.aspx/");
final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("form1");         
final HtmlSubmitInput button =  form.getInputByName("BtnLogin");
final HtmlTextInput textField =  form.getInputByName("Username");
final HtmlPasswordInput pwd =  form.getInputByName("password");        
textField.setValueAttribute("username");
pwd.setValueAttribute("password");      

final HtmlPage page2 =  button.getEnclosingForm().click();  
String htmlBody = page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString(); 

System.out.println("Base Uri 1 : "+page1);
System.out.println("Base Uri 2 : "+page2);

webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

But when I print `page2` it shows only the login page's url, and it is not returning the homepage url. What could be the problem ?

This is what I got in my console when clicked on form

> May 28, 2012 11:44:15 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered:'application/x-javascript'.
>   May 28, 2012 11:44:16 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'. 
>   Base Uri 1 : HtmlPage(http://www.ccstechnologies.org/login.aspx/)@2741851 
>   Base Uri 2 : HtmlPage(http://www.ccstechnologies.org/login.aspx/)@2741851

results generated when clicked on button

```
May 29, 2012 10:00:02 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:02 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: [259:24] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: [259:29] Error in style rule. Invalid token "\r\n   ". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
May 29, 2012 10:00:03 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: [259:29] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
HtmlPage(http://192.168.0.5/login.aspx)@23511316
HtmlPage(http://192.168.0.5/login.aspx)@17700115
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I looked into it, it would seem the problem was with the button. I replaced you line of code for the button with this:

```
 final HtmlPage page2 =  (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Login").click();
```

now it appears that it at least tries to login(and the page of course prints invalid login) so it should work with appropriate credentials.
to print the page in java and see it use system.out.println(page1.asText()) or asXml depending on what you want to see

my code is finally this:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);         
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);


     try{   final HtmlPage page1 =  webClient.getPage("http://www.ccstechnologies.org/login.aspx/");
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("form1");         
        final HtmlSubmitInput button =  form.getInputByName("BtnLogin");
        final HtmlTextInput textField =  form.getInputByName("Username");
        final HtmlPasswordInput pwd =  form.getInputByName("password");        
        textField.setValueAttribute("username");
        pwd.setValueAttribute("password");      
System.out.println(page1.asText());
        final HtmlPage page2 =  (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Login").click();

        String htmlBody = page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString(); 
        System.out.println(page2.asText());
       System.out.println("Base Uri 1 : "+page1);
      System.out.println("Base Uri 2 : "+page2);

        webClient.closeAllWindows();}catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Comment: Hi Joe, Very thanks for your effort . do u get the " invalid login " message ? However I tried your code and the results remains same.I think javascript is making some problem .....

Answer (score 3):

this is what you should set for the javascript:

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

and you can as well add these to it.

```
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
```

This should solve the problem as it did for me.

Comment: Kunbi Thanks for answer and your effort, but I am not lloking into this one problem right now, but iam sure this one will help me and others .... Thank you +1 :)

Comment: cookies are enabled in `CookieManager` by default.

Answer (score 1):

try to set cookies enabled, and try to set javascript enabled
ignore errors that it might print...(I used to think errors in red are bad, in html unit it seems not necessarily)

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for your answer I have updated the code as u see in the above code but  it doesnt do any good. problem still exists , pls let me know if u have any idea.. Thanks

Comment: As u see it generates some errors about java script but in the above case a clicked on the form.if i clicked on the button it generates more warnings updated my question with those outputs

Comment: ignore the warnings. simply print out page2 astext and see what page it prints, then you would know if it logged in or not... I had tonnes of warnings on websites before, and yet my code performed the desired action

Answer (score 1):

If the website uses an ajax call to login. 
This worked for me. Set this

```
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
```

This would cause all ajax calls to be synchronous.

This is how I setup my WebClient object

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
```